# how to resolve the data sources problem in terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

how can i use the data source in aws_security group.

i have a security group in my aws account how can i call the existing security group in my terraform code to newly created instance i am using the terraform data resouces but i am getting the error i have pasted the my code and error as well any one can please tell me how to resolve the error.

```
provider "aws" {
  profile = "default"
    region  = "us-east-2"
}
data "aws_vpc" "tesing" {

        filter {
        name = "tag:Name"
        values = ["test-vpc"]
        }

}
data "aws_security_group" "sg" {

        filter {
          name = "group-name"
          values = ["testing"]
        }
        filter {
        name = "vpc-id"
        values = ["data.aws_vpc.testing.id"]
        }

}

resource "aws_instance" "example" {
  ami           = "ami-03657b56516ab7912"
  instance_type = "t2.micro"
  vpc_security_group_ids = ["data.aws_security_group.sg.id"]
}

output "ipddress" {
  value = aws_instance.example.public_ip
}
```

i am getting the below error can u please help me out how to resolve the this error

```
Refreshing Terraform state in-memory prior to plan...
The refreshed state will be used to calculate this plan, but will not be
persisted to local or remote state storage.

data.aws_security_group.sg: Refreshing state...
data.aws_vpc.tesing: Refreshing state...

Error: InvalidParameterValue: vpc-id
        status code: 400, request id: 22e0f8c9-2265-4077-b271-6231b4787db1



Error: no matching VPC found
```

how to resolve this:

Answer (score 1):

First you have spelling mistake:

```
aws_vpc" "tesing"
```

It should be:

```
aws_vpc" "testing"
```

Second,

```
values = ["data.aws_vpc.testing.id"]
```

should be:

```
values = [data.aws_vpc.testing.id]
```

Comment: Refreshing Terraform state in-memory prior to plan...
The refreshed state will be used to calculate this plan, but will not be
persisted to local or remote state storage.
hi sir i made  the above changes but i am getting the below error
data.aws_vpc.testing: Refreshing state...

Error: no matching VPC found

Comment: sir my vpc is there in my account